# Custom interactive shell

Tags: c++, shell

I've run into the following problem: My console utility should be running as a process (hope it's the right term) so every command goes to it directly. Like gnuplot, interactive shells (irb, etc.).

This shows what I'm talking about:

```
Mikulas-Dites-Mac-2:Web rullaf$ command
Mikulas-Dites-Mac-2:Web rullaf$ irb
>> command
NameError: undefined local variable or method `command' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
>> exit
Mikulas-Dites-Mac-2:Web rullaf$
```

first `command` is executed as shell command, but after I enter `irb`, it's not. You get the point.

irb puts console into some special mode, or it simply parses the given input itself in some loop?
Is here any proper way to create such a behavior in c++? Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your question. You want to capture console input in your C++ program ? Why are  you talking about irb ?

Comment: @neuro Irb was simply an example of behavior I'm talking about and has nothing to do with my question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the input yourself. Depending on the complexity of the input, this might be accomplished by some simple string matching for trivial cases. A very simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string input;
  for(;;)
  {
    std::cout << ">>";
    std::cin >> input;
    if(input=="exit")
      return 0;
    else if(input=="test")
      std::cout << "Test!\n";
    else
      std::cout << "Unknown command.\n";
  }
}
```

Obviously, this little program will print a prompt (`>>`) and understand the commands `exit` and `test` and will print `Unknown command.` on all other commands.

For everything else, you probably want to learn some more about pattern matching or parsing; Google is your friend (take a look at [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for example and a good [tutorial](http://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html)).

Comment: Thanks, this is an obvious solution, yet I did want to have some more complicated commands - with dynamic number of parameters etc. Anyway, guess I'll have to write it myself.

Answer (score 2):

To parse your command line, you can use [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options.html).